# Set of Metapolynomials is closed under multiplication

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> We say that a function $f:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a
>   metapolynomial if, for some positive integer $m$ and $n$, it can be
>   represented in the form $$f(x_1,\cdots , x_k )=\max_{i=1,\cdots , m}
>  \min_{j=1,\cdots , n}P_{i,j}(x_1,\cdots , x_k),$$ where $P_{i,j}$ are
>   multivariate polynomials. Prove that the product of two
>   metapolynomials is also a metapolynomial.

This is a problem from the IMO Shortlist 2012. Can someone give me a solution? I have the shortlist booklet, and their solution seems pretty hard to think of, what I tried to do in this problem was take a $m\times n$ matrix and write $\displaystyle P_{i,j}$ in the $i,j$-th position. But I can't seem to be able to use it. Could someone tell me how to proceed after this, or give a different solution? In the artofproblemsolving site there's a solution using what I tried to do, but I don't get a word of it, and I am not used to that site. So I request you to help me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not my most awake self at the moment, but doesn't this condition say something like 'a function is metapolynomial if it is piecewise polynomial'? In that case you basically divide $\mathbb{R}^k$ in pieces corresponding to certain combinations of $(i,j)$ (where possibly not every combination occurs). I'll take a look at the IMO-solution, if there isn't any answer yet tomorrow.

Comment: @HSN did you reach anywhere conclusive? I suppose you are right, but how to employ the idea in the proof? Thanks for helping.